# Using variables with url constants in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to make something work with my vue app

I made constants.js file in which i just declare some of URLs I plan to recycle instead of rewriting them every time, but some of them require IDs of stuff

```js
#Example of constant definined in constants.js
export const useVariables = `https://myapiserver.com/iNeedVar1Here/${var1}/iNeedVar2here/${var2}`
```

And now I want to use this constant in my vue app and pass the variables where I need them, before sending the actual request

```js
getItem() {
            let var2 = this.formValues.item2;
            let var1 = this.formValues.item1;
            if (item != null) {
                axios.get(useVariables)
                    .then((res) => {
                        console.log(res.data)
                    })
                    .catch(err => console.log(err));
            }
            else {
                alert('Select an item before preceding')
            }
```

Comment: You should get this error `var2 & var1 is used before its declare, which is illegal for const variables`

Answer (score 2):

Your constant is static, it's not like a `computed` property or anything it's just a plain string so it won't work. Instead, you can create a function that will build and return the URL like this :

```
export const useVariables = (var1, var2) => `https://myapiserver.com/iNeedVar1Here/${var1}/iNeedVar2here/${var2}`
```

And then you can build the constant like this :

```js
getItem() {
  let var2 = this.formValues.item2;
  let var1 = this.formValues.item1;
  if (item != null) {
    axios.get(useVariables(var1, var2))
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data)
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  } else {
    alert('Select an item before preceding')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your current implementation, You will get the below error **:**

> var1 was used before it was declare, which is illegal for const variables

> var2 was used before it was declare, which is illegal for
> const variables

You have to pass these variables into a method and then have to return the concatenated string. You can give a try to this **:**

In some other utility file **:**

```
export function getAPIUrl(var1, var2) {
    return `https://myapiserver.com/iNeedVar1Here/${var1}/iNeedVar2here/${var2}`
}
```

In component **:**

```
import * as ApiUtil from '@/util/ApiUtil

axios.get(ApiUtil.getAPIUrl(var1, var2))
.then((res) => {
  console.log(res.data)
})
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```